# Summation of some factorial terms

Tags: summation, permutations, binomial-coefficients, factorial, binomial-theorem

I have an interesting series whose sum I know will be $0$, but not able to prove it. The series is

$$\sum_{i=0}^r \frac{(-1)^{i}}{i! (r-i)!}=0.$$ I had checked it for several values of $\text {“}r\text{''}$ and got the result, but was not able to show it. I got this observation while proving the Leibniz formula in case of distributions.

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Binomially expand $(1-1)^r$.

Answer (score 5):

Because its just $r!(1-1)^r=0$

Comment: what if i say that $\text r\in \mathbf R^n$

Comment: @bunny That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @bunny If $r\in\mathbb R^n$ then let $n=2$ and $r=(3,2)$. So we need to prove that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{(3,2)}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!((3,2)-i)!}=0.$ What is it???

Answer (score 4):

Multiply your sum by $r!$ You will obtain :

$$\sum_{i=0}^r  \binom{r}{i}  (-1)^{i}(1)^{n-i}$$

which is $0$ because it is the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^r.$